# Stackexchange not storing cookie consent - always showing banner

Tags: discussion

I'm using macOS Firefox 64.0.2 with acceptance of all cookies on.  Every time (or maybe it's every day) I see the "StackExchange uses cookies" banner.

I assume this is might be due to some annoying part of the GDPR. (And "lawyer/over-zealous-EU-bureacracy-fear-over-compliance.  I'm in the US - ironically, the *US* is supposed to be "land of the lawyers"!)

Is this a bug in the StackExcange software, or something about the GDPR and "how often" users must be "warned" (Wikipedia does keep my login), or an FF bug, or something else.

Comment: Are you logged in when you see this message?   Have you cleared your cookies (or set your browser to clear cookies when you close it)?   What does Wikipedia have to do with this?

Comment: Is this problem limited to Webmaster Stack Exchange or are you seeing it on other Stack Exchanges sites as well?